# Does ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION require INTERNET on wifi-only devices?

Tags: android, android-permissions

The only permission my app requires is ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.  I've gotten a few complaints from users that the app can't find their location.  Some of these come from wifi-only devices.

For wifi-only devices, does ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION require the INTERNET permission?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't require that you will add it to the permissions list, but if you are connected, you should get a better locations service, but that also depends:

it depends on the device, the manufacturer and the ROM itself. it can use any combination of sensors it sees fit, except for GPS.

If you wish, you can use Google Play services for getting the location, which is supposed to perform better than the normal way (more precise, faster, less batery,...) :

- http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
- https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html